# convert a MDX Calculation to DAX Calculation

Tags: dax, mdx, ssas-tabular

help me please,
I need to convert a MDX Calculation to DAX Calculation

```
tail({[Calendar].[Time].[dtDate].members},2).item(0)
```

I am trying to convert that mdx query to dax formula.
is there any simple way to write dax formula for that mdx query?

Comment: What is it that you want DAX to do? MDX to DAX isn't a direct conversion as they are two different modelling concepts. I think you may want to look at [`TOPN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/topn-function-dax)

Answer (score 0):

WHile I don't recommend this approach because DAX and MDX are different langugages.

So start by getting the maximum date from `Calendar` table, excluding any filters that might limit the dates considered.
Then calculate the second-to-last date `SecondMaxDate` by finding the maximum date that is less than `MaxDate`.

```
VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX([dtDate]), ALL('Calendar'))
VAR SecondMaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX([dtDate]), FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), [dtDate] < MaxDate))
RETURN SecondMaxDate
```